# How can I convert excel to PDF by Libreoffice and keep all format from excel file?

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, file-conversion

Currently, I can covert from excel to pdf by command line, but I have problem about front after convert. In excel file I used Times new roman font, but after convert to pdf I found the font in PDF file is different with it. Please help me how can I fix this problem.

P/s: My excel file in Japanese language, and I'm using Libreoffice 5.0 and centos 7

Comment: "Times New Roman" font has not any japanese glyphs. So Excel will using glyphs from "Yu Gothic" or "Meiryo" or "Arial Unicode MS" depending of the Windows System. So you possibly will see "Times New Roman" as font in Excel's GUI but the glyphs cannot be from that font. And while converting using a Linux system the font used will also be dependent on which installed font has appropriate glyphs in it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, bu could you tell me how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: What exact problem needs to be resolved? Japanese characters cannot be in font "Times New Roman". So another font needs to be used. Please describe your problem more precise. Use screen shot pictures to show with which result you are facing on. Describe what you don't like in that result and what you would like instead.

Comment: The excel file is https://gyazo.com/f18dbab47529fa065bff9f65b3298a9e  After convert my PDF like this https://gyazo.com/2022ab59905b804356c170076e87dc76 but my expectation  is https://gyazo.com/10de890da6d49598f7ddaa52404846a0

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments already "Times New Roman" font has not any Japanese glyphs. So Excel will using glyphs from supplement fonts "Yu Gothic" or "Meiryo" or "Arial Unicode MS" depending of the Windows System. So you possibly will see "Times New Roman" as font in Excel's GUI but the glyphs cannot be from that font.

First of all the system which shall create a PDF from the Excel file must have a font containing appropriate Japanese glyphs. The system is in your case the CentOS Linux Distribution. So at first do `# yum groupinstall "Japanese Support"` as described in [How to Install Asian Fonts on Red Hat & CentOS Linux Distributions](http://help.accusoft.com/PCC/v8.3/HTML/PCCIS_How%20to%20Install%20Asian%20Fonts%20on%20Red%20Hat%20and%20CentOS%20Linux%20Distributions.html).

And while converting using Libreoffice the supplement font used for Japanese characters will also be dependent on Libreoffice option settings. As far as I know there is not a directly possibility to set the font used. But dependent on the settings in

**Tools** - **Options** - **Language Settings** - **Language** - **Default Language for Documents** - [x] **Asian**: ...

[image]

different supplement fonts will be used.

For me for example, using Libreoffice 5.1.4.2 on Ubuntu Linux,

while "**Chinese (simplified)**" is set the font "**Noto Sans CJK SC Regular**" will be used,

but while "**Japanese**" is set the font "**TakaoPGothic**" will be used.

This settings also are influencing the command line

```
axel@arichter:~$ soffice --headless --convert-to pdf JapaneseExcel.xlsx
```

if **not** set "[ ] For the current document only".

So you could try different settings there.

To set the above options without GUI you must edit the file

```
/home/<user name>/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu
```

where `<user name>` is the name of the user which then will run the `soffice` command line.

In this file find the line:

```
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Common/I18N/CJK"><prop oor:name="AsianTypography" oor:op="fuse"><value>true</value></prop></item>
```

There the value must be set **true**. This will set the check-box [x] Asian.

Now find the line:

```
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Linguistic/General"><prop oor:name="DefaultLocale_CJK" oor:op="fuse"><value>ja-JP</value></prop></item>
```

The value **ja-JP** there sets the locale Japanese.

Now save the file `/home/<user name>/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu`.

---

Supplement:

As far as I see from your screen-shots, there are only Japanese characters in the whole sheet. So why using "Times New Roman" font at all? Why not using font "**Yu Gothic**" or "**Meiryo**" or "**MS Mincho**" for all cells? If so, this font setting will be stored in Excel's cell style settings and maybe then Libreoffice will using a font which is more similar to those. This I would try next if my first suggestion does not lead to a satisfying result.

Comment: @Tina: You wants to set "Default Language for Documents" on command line? I'm afraid there is not a command line command for. You would have to edit a config file in `/home/<user name>/.config/libreoffice/4/user`. I have not access to linux at the moment but I will checking this this evening. But what about using another font in Excel? Have you tried this?

Comment: @Tina:By the way, you have already installed fonts containing Japanese glyphs using `# yum groupinstall "Japanese Support"`, haven't you? See http://help.accusoft.com/PCC/v8.3/HTML/PCCIS_How%20to%20Install%20Asian%20Fonts%20on%20Red%20Hat%20and%20CentOS%20Linux%20Distributions.html. Because if there are only fonts having mainly Chinese glyphs ...

Comment: @Axcel thank you for your replying me. I have updated registrymodifications.xcu as you suggest but can't resolve this problem. Beside that, I can't run # yum groupinstall "Japanese Support"  (Warning: Group japanese-support does not have any packages to install.) Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: @Tina: I am not using CentOS. But the existence of fonts containing Japanese glyphs is essentially necessary for using Japanese glyphs. So if `# yum groupinstall "Japanese Support"` not works for you, you could ask why this not works and how to do this in `CentOS` as question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/centos7) or better suited in [Superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) in context of `centos` as tag.

Comment: i use the below to command to convert xlsx to pdf. i wanted to know is there a way to convert only the first sheet instead of all sheets.

libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf Apex.xlsx